# Formula to calculate sound volume loss per feet travelled in air

Tags: waves

I would like to know the formula to find what percentage/ratio of dB is lost per feet traveled. The medium we know is a normal air mixture with 45% humidity and a temperature if 73°F. Is there a formula to calculate how many decibels are lost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rate at which sound volume is lost is not constant with respect to distance.  Rather, it depends on the distance from the source of the sound:  the sound distance does not drop as much when moving from 100 m to 101 m away from the source as it does when moving from 1 meter to 2 meters away from the source.

The actual intensity of the sound can be affected by many things in the surrounding environment, for example:  the size and shape of the source; differences in the air temperature and humidity at different points in space<sup>1</sup>, as well as air flow;  the acoustical properties of any surfaces in the environment (the ground, walls, people, etc.)  However, if you want a rough and ready approximation, then you can use the fact that the intensity of a sound emitted from a "point source" (a physically small object) is inversely proportional to the square of the distance from the source.  This means if the intensity at a distance of 10 m is $I_0$ (say), the intensity at 20 m will be $I_0/4$.  The decibel level of the sound is related to its intensity by
$$
\text{decibels} = 10 \log_{10} \left( \frac{I}{I_\text{ref}} \right)
$$
where $I_\text{ref}$ is a reference intensity that doesn't end up mattering here.  Thus, we can conclude that
$$
(\text{decibels at 20 m}) - (\text{decibels at 10 m}) = 10 \log_{10} \left( \frac{I_0/4}{I_\text{ref}} \right) - 10 \log_{10} \left( \frac{I_0}{I_\text{ref}} \right) \\= 10 \log_{10} \left( \frac{I_0/4 I_\text{ref}}{I_0 / I_\text{ref}} \right) = 10 \log_{10} \frac{1}{4} = - 6.02.
$$
Thus, every time you **double** the distance to the source, the sound level decreases by about 6 decibels.  This is equally true when you go from 1 meter to 2 meters, 10 meters to 20 meters, or 100 meters to 200 meters.

More generally, if you want to calculate the change in sound level between any two distances $r_1$ and $r_2$ using this approximation, you would have $I_2/ I_1 = r_1^2 / r_2^2$ due to the inverse-square law.  By the same sort of logic as we had above, this then implies that
$$
(\text{decibels at $r_2$}) - (\text{decibels at $r_1$}) = 10 \log_{10}\left(\frac{I_2}{I_1} \right) = 10 \log_{10} \left(\frac{r_1^2}{r_2^2} \right) = 20 \log_{10} \left(\frac{r_1}{r_2} \right).
$$

---

<sup>1</sup> Note, however, that a constant temperature & humidity doesn't affect the propagation of sound intensity nearly as much as when there are different conditions in different locations.

Comment: So how would I calculate going from 38 to 40 feet?

Comment: @Riz-waan:  See my edited answer.  I haven't actually punched in your specific numbers, but for such a small change, the decrease in sound level will probably be minimal.

Comment: So I would calculate for my purposes as 20 log10 (38/40)?

Comment: I got that thanks, but here is a problem I see, what about going from 0 meters to 10 meters?

Comment: @Riz-waan:  It's only valid to approximate the source as a point when the distance to the source is significantly greater than the size of the source.  For example, if your source is a speaker that's 10 cm across, then you'd expect this equation to work for $r = 1$ meter, but it would fail for $r = 1$ cm.  And for no reasonable source of sound would it work at $r = 0$.